# SIPS to convert PDF to JPG + resize resulting JPGs?

Tags: macos, automation, automator, sips

Trying to use Automator to create thumbnail images for a bunch of PDFs. I want to convert the PDFs to JPGs, then downsize those JPGs. The first step has gone fine, but I've tried a bunch of ways to do the resize and nothing has worked... I'm not sure what I'm missing?

This is working great for the PDF to JPG part:

```
for f in "$@"
do
 sips -s format jpeg -s formatOptions 100 "$f" --out "${f%.pdf}.jpg";
 echo "${f%.pdf}.jpg"
done
```

This is what I'd like to add:

```
 sips –z 200 *.jpg -s formatOptions 100
```

I've tried adding it as a second line, tried putting just the -z section within the existing line, tried an entirely separate step in Automator...

Would love to work this out. Thank you!

Comment: Please re-read and carefully check your first 2 sentences - they don't appear to make sense or match your code.

Comment: Typos abound.  sips -Z 200 *.jpg might well do what you want and preserve the aspect ratio. NB **Z** is capital z!  sips -z takes two parameters yheight xwidth (and can alter the aspect ratio). Capitalisation and exact syntax is very important here! Surprised you didn't get a helpful error message.

Comment: Thanks @MartinBrown, that's interesting. I saw a lot of lowercase z's in my searching, and didn't realize Z and z both do different things. I am indeed trying to retain aspect ratio and thus Z should be the one. That said, I've now got

`for f in "$@"
do
 sips -s format jpeg -s formatOptions 100 "$f" --out "${f%.pdf}.jpg";
 sips –Z 200 *.jpg -s formatOptions 100
done`

and it's still not doing the resize.

Comment: Why are you processing ***all*** the JPEGs (with your asterisk) every time you process one PDF?

Comment: I'm not processing one PDF. I am converting multiple PDFs into multiple JPGs, and I want all of the resulting JPGs to be downsized.

Comment: Surely if you run your script and specify 17 PDFs as parameters, you will go through your `for` loop 17 times… and on each pass through the loop you will process all JPEGs in the directory because of the asterisk.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean now. I'm sorry, I have minimal knowledge of code so I'm trying to piece this together from what others have shared about their sips workflows. I've now tried removing the `*.jpg` - both just leaving it out and replacing it with `"$f"` - and also removing the formatOptions portion to just focus on the resize for now... and none of these have gotten me resized JPGs either.

Comment: Ah I got it... `for f in "$@"
do
 sips -s format jpeg -s formatOptions 100 "$f" --out "${f%.pdf}.jpg";
 echo "${f%.pdf}.jpg";
 sips -Z 200 -s formatOptions 100 "$f"
 echo "$f.jpg";
done`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do, or what the problem is. Here is a simple way of doing what I think you want all in one go:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in "$@" ; do
  outfile=${f%.pdf}.jpg
  sips -s format jpeg -s formatOptions 100 -Z 200 "$f" --out "$outfile"
done
```

---

If you want to do it in two steps for some unknown reason, you can use:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in "$@" ; do
  outfile=${f%.pdf}.jpg
  sips -s format jpeg -s formatOptions 100 "$f" --out "$outfile"
  sips -s formatOptions 100 -Z 200 "$outfile" --out "$outfile"
done
```